# making header file than can be used anywhere for iphone

Tags: iphone

i want to make headerfile Rimage.h and m that i can use anywhere but i have a problem here
this is my

Rimage.h

```
@class Rahul_imageplaceCordinatesViewController;

@interface Rimage : NSObject {

    Rahul_imageplaceCordinatesViewController *vc;
}

-(void)addImageSubViewAtX:(CGFloat)x atY:(CGFloat)y;
@property (nonatomic,copy) Rahul_imageplaceCordinatesViewController *vc;
+(void)check1;

@end
```

and this is my .m

```
@implementation Rimage
@synthesize vc;

/// this method let you have image with given X n Y
- (void)addImageSubViewAtX:(CGFloat)x atY:(CGFloat)y {
CGRect myImageRect1 = CGRectMake(x, y, 30.0f, 30.0f); 
    UIImageView *myImage1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect1]; 

    [myImage1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"status_finish.gif"]]; 
    myImage1.tag = 1000;

    myImage1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:myImage1];    
}
```

now in my mainVC

i am calling like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {    
    Rimage *hw = [[Rimage alloc] init];

    //[hw check1];
    [Rimage check1];
    [hw addImageSubViewAtX:160.0 atY:190.0];        
}
```

but i cant display that image   i dont know why :(

Answer (score 0):

First I noticed is your @property you are making a "copy" of the ViewController in vc, I suspect that's a bad idea, you just want to assign or retain it.

Second, in addImageSubViewAtX, you have:

```
[self.view addSubview:myImage1];
```

But what is self there?  It is the instance of Rimage.  I'm guessing that perhaps you meant to add the image to the view in vc??  I don't see that vc is ever used in the code you provided so what is it for?

```
[vc.view addSubview:myImage1];
```

Comment: so what should i do in order to display image using this headerfile only so that it can be generic??

Comment: if i do this [vc.view addSubview:myImage1];

then its running infinite